# VBA Word Expand Range with one line

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, range

First of all this is the first time I am creating a macro using VBA code. With some bits and pieces i found on the internet I tried to create the following. I am not a developer at all, I just have some basic knowledge from school. So my apologies if this is poor coding.

I am creating a macro in word which highlights text from a paragraph heading until the next heading with the same style. This is done based on a list of headings I import from Excel. You can find the code I have created below. The result with few input is perfect, so that's a good thing! The execution is very slow though (3 to 4h), which is probably related to the many selects I use. (I read only this is very often the cause of slow macros)

I tried to expand my Range with one line at the time using " Range.Expand Unit:=wdLine " but it's giving me errors every time. Therefore I use the moveDown selection method now which is doing the trick. Does anyone know a way I could use ranges here to speed up the process?

Many thanks in advance.

```
    Sub Highlight_WordN()
Dim par As Paragraph
Dim par2 As Paragraph
Dim doc As Document
Dim oRng As Range
Dim Sty As Style
Dim intCurrentLine As Integer
Dim strFindArray() As String
Dim strIn As String
Dim strWorkBookName As String
Dim strNumberCells As String
Dim MessageFound As String
Dim MessageNotFound As String
Dim Flag As Boolean
Dim IsHeading As Boolean
Dim IsNothing As Boolean

'*****Set parameters for performance*****

    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Word.Application.Options.CheckGrammarAsYouType = False
    Word.Application.Options.CheckGrammarWithSpelling = False
    Word.Application.Options.CheckSpellingAsYouType = False
    Word.Application.Options.AnimateScreenMovements = False
    Word.Application.Options.BackgroundSave = False
    Word.Application.Options.CheckHangulEndings = False
    Word.Application.Options.DisableFeaturesbyDefault = True

'*****Load data from excel*****
'List of headers to delete

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Object
    strWorkBookName = "C:\Users\driesenn\OneDrive\OMAR\UPDATE\ToDelete.xlsx"
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strWorkBookName)
    xlApp.Visible = False
    ArrayLen = 0
    ArrayLen = xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range("B1")
    strNumberCells = "A1:A" & ArrayLen
    strArray = xlApp.Transpose(xlApp.ActiveSheet.Range(strNumberCells))
    ArrayLen = 0
    ArrayLen = UBound(strArray) - LBound(strArray) + 1
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing

'*****Start evaluation process for headers*****

ArrayLen = UBound(strArray) - LBound(strArray) + 1

'Loop over all headers in the array
For i = 1 To ArrayLen
    strFind = strArray(i)

    'Evaluate every paragraph heading
    For Each par In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If par.Style Like "Heading*" Then
            Set Sty = par.Style

            'Search for the header number in the heading
            If InStr(par.Range.Text, strFind) = 1 Then
                Set oRng = par.Range
                oRng.Select
                intCurrentLine = oRng.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
                Set oRng = Selection.Next(Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1)

                'If the next line is not a header --> go on
                IsHeading = False
                If oRng.Style Like "Heading*" Then
                    IsHeading = True
                End If

                'Keep looping until the next heading of this type is found
                Do While oRng.Style > Sty Or IsHeading = False
                    Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
                    Set oRng = Selection.Next(Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1)
                    If oRng Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If

                    'If the next line is not a header --> go on
                    IsHeading = False
                    If oRng.Style Like "Heading*" Then
                    IsHeading = True
                    End If
                Loop

                Selection.Start = par.Range.Start
                'If we are not at the end of the document selection ends with last line of current range.
                If oRng Is Nothing Then

                Else
                    Selection.End = oRng.Start
                End If

                'Set highlight
                Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you tell us *"giving me errors every time"* you should also include *which* errors you get and *where* exactly in the code the errors occur. Otherwise the information is quite useless for us to help.

Comment: Also, not sure what you mean by expand your range? Do you mean your paragraph in Word? BTW, it's not a bad effort for someone who just has some basic knowledge from school :) **Note**: Use `Option Explicit`. It will help with things like variable declarations

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. I start with a range of one line, being the paragraph heading. From there I want to expand my selection/range with one line at the time and check if the last line is of the type "heading". If not I expand the selection once more.

Until now I used this code so my selection is enlarged with one line. 
Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend

But I want to use the following to not use the selection but range instead.
oRng.Expand Unit:=wdLine

Although when this line is executed it gives the error Run-time error '4120' bad parameter

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it will assist you to become familiar with using help. Place your cursor in the keyword that you need help with and press F1. Had you done so for the Expand method you would have landed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.range.expand). You will find the valid parameters for *Unit* are listed.

Secondly, paragraph styles are applied to *paragraphs* not lines. So you need to check the style of each paragraph and expand the range by one paragraph at a time. This will enable you to avoid selecting anything.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for the answer. I have tried now Range.Expand Unit:=wdParagraph but this stays within the same paragraph and I want to include the next paragraph in my selection. What is the option here?

Comment: If the range doesn't already contain an entire paragraph expanding it will only extend it to the end of the paragraph the range is contained by. So you need to make sure that your range object already contains a para to begin with.

Comment: Hi Timothy,
Thanks for the answer. My range exists of exactly one paragraph. How do I expand it to include the next paragraph too? Is there a way to make the step to the next paragraph without losing the existing range?

Comment: I just checked this in O365 and you are absolutely correct. However, rng.MoveEnd wdParagraph will expand to the next paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows a much easier way of highlighting the ranges associated with different heading levels, using Word's built-in '\HeadingLevel' bookmark:

```
Sub Demo()
Dim h As Long, c As Long, Rng As Range
For h = 1 To 9
  With ActiveDocument.Range
    With .Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = ""
      .Style = "Heading " & h
      .Replacement.Text = ""
      .Format = True
      .Forward = True
      .Execute
    End With
    Do While .Find.Found
      Set Rng = .Paragraphs(1).Range
      Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel")
      Select Case h
        Case 1 To 4: c = h + 1
        Case 5: c = h + 2
        Case 6 To 8: c = h + 4
        Case 9: c = h + 5
        Case Else: c = 0
      End Select
      Rng.HighlightColorIndex = c
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        If .End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1 Then
          .End = .Cells(1).Range.End
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          If .Information(wdAtEndOfRowMarker) = True Then .End = .End + 1
        End If
      End If
      If .End = ActiveDocument.Range.End Then Exit Do
      .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      .Find.Execute
    Loop
  End With
Next
End Sub
```

Of course, as the above code loops through all 9 heading levels, what ends up with a given highlight depends on how many other lower-level headings (higher numbers) are nested within a given higher-level heading (lower numbers).