# How to find out, if `Selection.GoTo` was successful?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Inside a MS Word macro, I can use `Selection.GoTo` to find the next header. As a result, I get a `Range`.

I would like to use this inside a `While`...`Wend` loop.

How can I find out, if there is a further header available? Or with other words: How can I find out, if `GoTo` was successfull?

Comment: GoTo changes the Selection. You can query the Selection to tell you which Header it's in. Rather than going to Headers you name consider looping through all Headers and modifying them, or going to them if you must, only if they exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using Selection? That's usually much less efficient than working with ranges. In any event, if you test whether the existing \HeadingLevel bookmark extends to the end of the document, you'll have your answer. For example:

```
Sub Demo()
MsgBox Selection.Range.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\HeadingLevel").End + 1 = ActiveDocument.Range.End
End Sub
```

Comment: "Why?" ... because this is my very first VBA program. ;-) Thank you for you help!

Comment: To see how the \HeadingLevel bookmark can be used with range objects, check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856477/adding-code-for-extracting-headings-from-word-comments-into-excel & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61056236/vba-word-expand-range-with-one-line/61058927#61058927

Answer (score 0):

Headers and Footers are a challenging concept in MS Word.  If you are working with Headers and Footers there are three Key Items that you need to understand

1. Headers and Footers are a property of Sections
2. each Section has 3 headers and 3 footers
3. The definition of the header/footers lives in the section break at the end of the section

I strangly recommend you read up on Headers and Fotters before trying to code with them.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.headerfooter